# Recursion via stack<> goes on heap?

Tags: recursion, stack, overflow

I need to translate my recursive function into a stack-form, since my program ends up with a stack overflow. I am using Unity3D C#, and somewhere I saw that it's something like 5MB size for the program.

My question is, will the stack of references to items be held on the heap or still in the stack? I guess it's pretty obvious that it will go on the heap, but it's not clear to me why.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you create a new `object` (`reference` type) it goes to the heap (dynamic allocation), so when you'll use a new instance of `Stack` (data structure, not to be confused with memory stack) it'll be allocated on the heap. `Stack` is a `reference` type, not a value type.

Comment: Thank you! Just as I thought then